# Create a new table from existing table

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

A bit of a random exercise but I want to take content from an existing table and create a new table based on the entries taken.

[image]

In the image above, the table on the left is what I have to work with already. The blue table on the right is what I want to create; using the data from the table on the left.

Can this be done with jQuery or some basic PHP?

If you're wondering why I'm doing this its because I don't have access to the SQL database and I want to use Google Charts API to display  total number of user registrations for each month.

As always, your help is MUCH appreciated.

Comment: Bein able to see the html code from the left table would help us write a more accurate answer, but on first impression, it can be achived with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery it can be done in this way

```
//initialize monthArray
var monthArr = [{month:'April', occ:0}, {month:'May', occ:0},{month:'June', occ:0}];

//read occurrences for MonthNames in your existing table
$.each(monthArr, function(n,i){
    var _occ = $("td:contains('"+monthArr[n].month+"')").size();
    monthArr[n].occ = _occ;
});

// create new table and show the values
$.each(monthArr, function(index, value) {
  //alert(value.occ+ ': ' + value.month);
    $('#inTable').append('<tr><td>'+value.month+'</td><td>'+value.occ+'</td></tr>');
});
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A3WeJ/38/

Note: Table look and feel formatting has not been done in this solution

Answer (score 0):

The question of whether or not you wish to use jQuery or PHP depends on whether the content of these tables is likely to change after the page has loaded. If the page will not change, you should use PHP.

Assuming the table is produced using a `while` or `foreach` loop, you can simply set up counts for each option that you have in the table. Within the loop, if you check what is in this column and add to an appropriate arbitrary count, you can count how many are in each.

It would probably be good to check what the contents is, and if it's already in your array.

Hope that provides some initial help to the thinking behind this question!

Comment: I think (I'm not completely sure) he has no access to the database, so he want to create the right table from the HTML output of the left table.

Comment: @aleation Ah okay, if this is the case jQuery/Javascript will be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this (You didn't provide more information, so just may be an idea)

**HTML** The id `maintable` could be changed with another id/class or just `table`

```
​<table id="maintable">
    <thead><th>Name</th><th>Join Month</th><th>Join Year</th></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Joe Blogs</td><td>April</td><td>2012</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Mr. X</td><td>April</td><td>2012</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Andrew Xmen</td><td>April</td><td>2012</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Matt Bblogs</td><td>may</td><td>2012</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Malcom McGuiness</td><td>June</td><td>2012</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Friday Needavodka</td><td>June</td><td>2012</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="myTblDiv"></div>
```

**JS**

```
​$(function(){
    var rows={};
    $('table#maintable tbody tr').each(function(){
        var item=$('td:eq(1)', $(this));
        if(rows.hasOwnProperty(item.text()))
            rows[item.text()]=parseInt(rows[item.text()])+1;
        else rows[item.text()]=1;
    });

    var myTable=$('<table />', {'id':'myNewtable', 'class':'table table-striped'});
    var th=$('<thead><th>Total</th><th>Month</th></thead>');
    var tbody=$('<tbody></tbody>');
    myTable.append(th).append(tbody);
    $.each(rows, function(k, v){
        var row=$('<tr><td>'+v+'</td><td>'+k+'</td></tr>');
        myTable.find('tbody').append(row);
    });
    $('div#myTblDiv').append(myTable);
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DwS4L/2/) or [**Different Style**](http://jsfiddle.net/QKqhH/).

Notice, I've used an id `(maintable)` for the table generated by google, in this case you have to change the `id` or `class` (if it has any) or even you can just use `table` without any id or class name but make sure there is only one table when you are using only `$('table')`, also if you can wrap the table within a parent div then you can use `$('div#parentDivId table')`.